Book I read in Jr. High about a young boy on a massive ship who wanders down to a slave labor section
The book was about a young boy who (I believe) was on a massive ship. On the ship there was slave labor or something close to it, in the belly of the ship. Which was restricted to him and the other members of the populace above that section. He wanders down anyways and finds it’s not what they are told it is. And comes into contact with a girl who is about the same age he is. After that I can’t really remember much of the story, but I’m open to any suggestions about what this book might be. It’s been driving me crazy about what it’s called for years now. Makes me wish I had made a list of every book I’d ever read growing up.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this?

How is it science fiction or fantasy? Is the ship a space ship?

I am pretty sure I have read that story, ages ago. I believe it was a short story or novelette rather than a full novel.

Possibly Worldshaker by Richard Harland?


In this gripping fantasy, Col lives on the Upper Decks of the juggernaut Worldshaker – a mobile city as big as a mountain. Chosen to be the next Supreme Commander, Col’s comfortable life is upset when a ‘Filthy’, who has escaped from Below, appears in his cabin, begging for help. Will he hand her over, or will he break all the rules? Col’s safe, elite world is about to fall apart.

It's not an exact match as Col is aboard a mobile city not an ocean liner, and he doesn't explore the lower decks - the girl hides in his cabin. But overall the storyline is close to what you describe.
You don't say when you read the book, but this was published in 2009 if that helps.
